# ApolloClient: Delete item from cache across all queries?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I'm familar with the various ways to perform updates and inserts when it comes to ApolloClient cache, but this question is about deletes.

Let's say the user chooses to delete "note" item with an "id" of 123. I want "note:123" deleted altogether within the cache. Is there a way to do this?

For example, in the case of doing updates, I often use `writeFragment` to update a specific note, and that does what I expect, updating that note across all queries. However, I notice a conspicuous lack of a `deleteFragment` method. Am I missing something?

Comment: You just want to delete the item with an id of 123 in the cache query or delete all data in the cache?

Comment: I just want to delete that item. i.e. the user deleted the note, therefore that note shouldn't appear in any queries anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ApolloClient v3 lets you use [evict()](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/caching/cache-interaction/#garbage-collection-and-cache-eviction) for this. As far as I know, this is the only way to delete an item without needing to know every combination of queries and variables it's appeared under.

Answer (score 0):

You can you `update` options to update your cache after the mutation. Try this:

```js
const DELETE_ITEM = gql`
  DeleteItem($id: ID!) {
    deleteItem(id: $id) {
      ...
    }
  }
`

const LIST_ITEMS = gql`
  ListItem($query: ListItemInput!) {
    listItem(query: $query) {
      items {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`

const [deleteItem] = useMutation(DELETE_ITEM, {
  update: (cache, { deleteItem }) => {
    const { listItem } = cache.readQuery(LIST_ITEMS, {
      variables: {
        query: {...}
      }
    })
    const index = listItem.items.findIndex(
      item => item.id === deleteMessage.id
    )
    if (index > -1) {
      listItem.items.splice(index, 1)
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: LIST_ITEMS,
        {
          variables: {
            query: {...}
          }
        },
        data: {
          listItem,
        },
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This only updates the cache for a single query. But a single item might be in any number of queries.